# Can I somehow use the to_field parameter in a Django ManyToMany field?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django's `ForeignKey` field I can specify the `to_field`. This is great, as I can use slugs as foreign keys and do the equivalent of the 'natural key' functionality.

I can't find any such field in `ManyToMany`. I don't see why not. Is there some way to do this? Perhaps do it explicitly in my own m2m join table with `through`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Django has a build-in `to_field` parameter for `ManyToManyField`. However like you mentioned you can manually make a `through` table, which obviously will use `ForeignKey` fields, which do support `to_field` parameter.

Not really a clean method and does not follow the DRY, but I don't think there is any better way of currently solving this problem. Perhaps you should file a feature request for this.