# Django to_field for ManytoMany?

Tags: django, django-models

(Using Django 1.10) If I have a model `Person` that has a field `person_state` with a ManytoMany relationship with model `State`, can I store *actual names* of the State in `person_state` instead of pk?

```
person_state = models.ManyToManyField(State, blank=True,related_name='person_state')
```

Looks like I can't have a `to_field` in `ManytoManyField` (which [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13128127/1526703) post and the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) confirm) but I'd guess this to be a pretty common use case (i.e entities referring to other entities (in a manytomany relationship) by their names instead of pk's). Please let me know if I am thinking about it incorrectly.

Comment: You could probably use a custom through table, whose ForeignKeys define `to_field`. I can't see why you'd want to do this, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Daniel. I have a feeling that I am not doing this right or I dont understand ManytoManyField fully yet. I have a model State which should contain geographic states. When the user enters their State in a web form, they would enter (or select) it by it's name. Do you mean the ideal way is for me to first find out the corresponding pk in the State model and then assign that to `person_state` instead of directly assigning the name string?

Comment: I should also mention that I am also trying to populate the Person model from a csv that contains State(s) by their names (hence having `person_state` by name will ease that process as well)

Comment: Well are you sure you want a many-to-many in the first place? You seem to be talking about a person having a single state, in which case it's a foreign key. But the presentation of the selection list is the responsibility of the form, not the model; and you can easily set it to show the name attribute rather than the pk.

Comment: Yeah, actually in this usecase, its a many-to-many (a Person can be associated with more than one State and vice-versa). On the presentation side, State will be by name only. What I was asking was that when they select (or enter a new) State by name on the web form, if I can save that name directly as `person_state` in the view instead of first finding the corresponding pk and then assigning it to the pk.

Comment: After thinking more and reading up a bit, I think I'll go ahead and just use pk since it seems surrogate keys work best with Django and better for performance too since my tables may get large over time.